# How do you extract multiple values from JSON?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file like this:

```
print(resp)
dataList = []
{
  "totalCount": 9812,
  "pageSize": 50,
  "nextPageKey": "12345",
  "problems": [
    {
      "problemId": "1234",
      "displayId": "test1",
      "title": "host memory saturation",
      "impactLevel": "INFRASTRUCTURE",
      "severityLevel": "RESOURCE_CONTENTION",
      "status": "OPEN"
     }
     ]
}
```

I need to extract "title", "impactLevel" and "severityLevel" and create a data frame out this:

I have tried this:

```
dataList.append([resp['problems'][0]['title']['impactLevel']['severityLevel']])
hyperEntitydf = pd.DataFrame(dataList, columns=['Alert','Type','Severity'])
hyperEntitydf=hyperEntitydf.drop_duplicates()
print(hyperEntitydf.head())
```

On this line:

```
 dataList.append([resp['problems'][0]['title']['impactLevel']['severityLevel']])
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Is it possible to extract multiple fields with one call?

```
dataList.append([resp['problems'][0]['title']['impactLevel']['severityLevel']])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. For this to work, the json would need to be nested such that impactLevel were within title, and severityLevel were within impactLevel.

I'd suggest

```
x = resp['problems'][0]
dataList.append([x['title'], x['impactLevel', x['severityLevel'])
```

Unless, you want *all* the fields of the json, in which case you can do:

```
dataList.append(list(resp['problems'][0].values()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `operators.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

f = itemgetter('title', 'impactLevel', 'severityLevel')
dataList.append(list(f(resp['problems'][0])))
```

You only need to use `list` if you specifically need a list; `f` will return a tuple.

If you want the three values from every element of `resp['problems']`,

```
dataList = list(map(f, resp['problems']))
```

Here, you only need `list` if `DataFrame` requires a list, rather than an arbitrary iterable.